# Удаление MySQL Community Server

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Как мне удалить MySQL полностью?
При запуске Installer'a появляется такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Я хочу удалить, то появляется ошибка:   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужн при первом запуске вот такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Community Server у Вас уже удалён. Если верить скриншотам, конечно...

Connector у Вас либо повреждён, либо не с-под админа делаете... Можно удалить вручную (но муторно, и можно накосячить), а можно выполнить сперва Modify либо Upgrade, чтобы восстановить состояние коннектора до нормального, а потом удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую